# How to write a urls.py in django so that I can do something like */page

Tags: django, django-urls

Here is the problem:

- I have an app with the following models: project, position, outreach
- A position is connected to a project and project only with a Foreign key
- An outreach is connected to a position and a position only with a Foreign key

I can create a new project from almost anywhere in my app (same for the other objects). Currently I wrote that a new project is created from the url `dashboard/newjobproject` but I would to make it so that depending on the page that I am, the url simply becomes something like `www.myapp.com/..../newproject`

What's a way to write the `urls.py` to achieve that?

```
from django.urls import path
from action import views

app_name = 'action'

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /action/
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('contacts/', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
    path('projects/', views.project, name='project'),

    path('contacts/newcontact', views.new_contact, name='new_contact'),
    path('projects/newjobproject', views.new_outreach, name='new_outreach'),
    path('dashboard/newjobproject', views.new_jobproject, name='new_jobproject'),
    path('projects/<uuid>/newjobposition', views.new_jobposition, name='new_jobposition'),
    
]
```

However,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the bottom of urlpatterns:

```
path('<path:p>/newjobproject', views.new_jobproject, name='whatever-name-you-want'),
```

and in your views.py:

```
def new_jobproject(request, p):
```

Tbh though, this is sort of a hacky way to do it. It'll break in a few locations. If you have a main urlpatterns array in which you're including the urls for this 'action' app as APIs, this solution won't work outside the API urls.

For eg. if you have:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('api/v1/', include('action.urls')),
]
```

And you access your url like this -> `www.myapp.com/api/v1/....../newjobproject`, then the code will work. If you try to access `www.myapp.com/..../newjobproject` or `www.myapp.com/admin/..../newjobproject` then the code will break and it will not match any of the paths. I'm not sure how you'd get it to work in that case.

If the above scenario is not an issue, if you're not going to be using these views as APIs, and your urlpatterns looks something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin', admin.site.urls),
  path('/', include('action.urls')),
]
```

then the code *should* work for all urls except for the admin/.../newjobproject case.

Comment: Thanks! This is good input! I think you are right and it might break but I am going to see if I can tweak things around and make it work ! Thanks!